# Deleted MySQL "root" user (using phpMyAdmin)...how to restore?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, users

I'm test-running a Joomla installation (locally, using WAMP) with an MySQL database supporting it...this is in preparation to moving everything online once I have it configured.

I was working in phpMyAdmin to change the password of a superuser I had set up with a login-name other than "root."  While doing so, I saw three additional "root" users, and on the phpMyAdmin home page, a warning about these root users not having a password.  I thought that since I created my own superuser with "All Privileges," I didn't need the root users...so I deleted them.  Immediately things stopped working...and now, when I click on the "Users" tab in phpMyAdmin, it simply returns a red bar that says "No Privileges"...my specific superuser is gone.  However, it seems I can still move around in phpMyAdmin (maybe because I'm still logged in?).

Could someone *please* tell me step-by-step how (if?) I can re-add the root users using phpMyAdmin?  I see instructions posted in various places, but they seem to address users who are using terminal windows or some other program.  I'd  hate to see months of work go down the drain!

EDIT:  Using Windows, I've tried the following:

1. There is no file called "resetroot.bat" anywhere in the wamp/sql folders, as someone suggested...so that option is out.
2. I've tried to access MySQL using a terminal connection:  in the MySQL root folder there is a file called **mysql.exe** that *seems* to grant this when executed (there is no "mysql_safe.exe" as some solutions have suggested).  However, I have been unsuccessful in starting mysql with the **--skip-grant-tables** option from *outside* **mysql.exe**, and when I try to do it from within **mysql.exe**, I just get an odd prompt ("->") and no other commands seem to work.

Please keep in mind that I am a newbie at this!  I am trying different things, but without any success...that is why I'll probably need step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I finally found a solution.  To give proper credit, I had to blend answers provided by two people:  RiggsFolly's answer to [this question on resetting the root password in wamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724808/phpmyadmin-in-wamp-error-1045-need-to-reset-password/22784404#22784404), which is what I'm using, and jm666's answer for [this question on restoring a deleted root user in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085455/restoring-deleted-root-user-and-password-for-mysql/6085548#6085548) using MAMP on OS X.

For Wamp Users:

1. Click on the Wamp system tray icon to bring up the tray menu.  Click
   **MySQL** > **Service** > **Stop Service**.
2. Edit your MySQL's **my.ini** file...that's your configuration file for your SQL database, and it's generally located in the root folder for your MySQL database (try looking in **wamp** > **bin** > **mysql** > **mysql5.5** *[or whatever version]*).  Use a text editor, and scroll down in the my.ini file to `[wampmysqld]`.  Immediately after this entry, insert a new line containing the following command:

   `skip-grant-tables` 
   This tells the MySQL database that you want to override any restrictions such as root user or password parameters.  *This is a **major** security hole, so once we are done with our repairs, we'll need to undo this!*  Save the my.ini file.
3. Resume MySQL services in Wamp (click **MySQL** > **Service** > **Start/Resume Service**).
4. Now open the MySQL console:  click **MySQL** > **MySQL Console**
5. A "DOS-like" terminal window will open up (if it asks you for a password, simply press enter).  You should see a MySQL prompt.  Copy the following block of code and paste it at the prompt.

   ```
   INSERT INTO mysql.user
   SET user = 'root', 
   host = 'localhost', 
   password = '', 
   Select_priv = 'y',
   Insert_priv = 'y',
   Update_priv = 'y',
   Delete_priv = 'y',
   Create_priv = 'y',
   Drop_priv = 'y',
   Reload_priv = 'y',
   Shutdown_priv = 'y',
   Process_priv = 'y',
   File_priv = 'y',
   Grant_priv = 'y',
   References_priv = 'y',
   Index_priv = 'y',
   Alter_priv = 'y',
   Show_db_priv = 'y',
   Super_priv = 'y',
   Create_tmp_table_priv = 'y',
   Lock_tables_priv = 'y',
   Execute_priv = 'y',
   Repl_slave_priv = 'y',
   Repl_client_priv = 'y',
   Create_view_priv = 'y',
   Show_view_priv = 'y',
   Create_routine_priv = 'y',
   Alter_routine_priv = 'y',
   Create_user_priv = 'y',
   Event_priv = 'y',
   Trigger_priv = 'y',
   Create_tablespace_priv = 'y';
   ```
6. Press enter.  You should get some sort of message saying that one line (of database code) was affected, with some warnings (probably because you are messing with the root user...I think you can safely ignore these).  Close the MySQL terminal.
7. Remember that security hole we opened in step two?  Time to fix that.  Reopen your my.ini SQL configuration file, and remove the `skip-grant-tables` line you added.  Save the my.ini file and close.
8. RESTART your MySQL Service (same as before, but click on **MySQL** > **Service** > **Restart Services** instead).

THAT should do the trick!

A note on the **root** user in MySQL for newbies:  for some strange reason, even if you create another user as a superuser, MySQL seems to need this user to operate...however, if you don't set up a password for root, it notes this as a security hole.  Whatever you do, don't delete it:  you're better off just setting some wildly obscure password for it and leaving it alone if you want to use another superuser account.  It would seem that there should be more protections to help prevent unwary users from doing this (a warning, or something)....that's my twelve cents on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to [Superion's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/124899/125613):

If your problem is you have root user, but somehow you set your priviledges to 'n' and now you can't change anything; in step 5, you can update the root to change priviledges to 'y' by copying & pasting this:

```
UPDATE mysql.user
SET Select_priv = 'y',
Insert_priv = 'y',
Update_priv = 'y',
Delete_priv = 'y',
Create_priv = 'y',
Drop_priv = 'y',
Reload_priv = 'y',
Shutdown_priv = 'y',
Process_priv = 'y',
File_priv = 'y',
Grant_priv = 'y',
References_priv = 'y',
Index_priv = 'y',
Alter_priv = 'y',
Show_db_priv = 'y',
Super_priv = 'y',
Create_tmp_table_priv = 'y',
Lock_tables_priv = 'y',
Execute_priv = 'y',
Repl_slave_priv = 'y',
Repl_client_priv = 'y',
Create_view_priv = 'y',
Show_view_priv = 'y',
Create_routine_priv = 'y',
Alter_routine_priv = 'y',
Create_user_priv = 'y',
Event_priv = 'y',
Trigger_priv = 'y',
Create_tablespace_priv = 'y'
WHERE User = 'root';
```

Now you have all rights on root again. Thanks goes to @Superion.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you mean MySQL.

Open your local folder for MySQL look for the **bin** folder then run the **resetroot.bat** file.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response!  Unfortunately, I don't have a "bin" folder nor a "resetroot.bat" file in my local mysql folder.

Comment: what folders do you have

Answer (score -1):

`mysqld`, not `mysql`, is the command that needs --skip-grant-tables

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,507039,507042#msg-507042