# Deleted MySQL “root” user in phpMyAdmin through XAMPP local host…how to restore?

Tags: mysql, restore, phpmyadmin, xampp, root

I was working in phpMyAdmin (XAMPP localhost) to add a user for a new database I created for a local WordPress website, and came upon the list of users named "root". Since I did not remember ever creating these root users, I tried to delete them. I don't know what I clicked. I don't remember hitting any delete button, but this resulted in deletion of root. After that, all my databases were gone along with all users. Now only "Database operations information_schema" is there in phpMyAdmin panel.  Now when I click on the "Databases" tab in phpMyAdmin, it simply returns a red warning "No privileges to create databases". There's no user tab. I can still see my databases in MySQL folder in XAMPP folder, and all WordPress websites work fine. But I am unable to create a new database/user nor am I seeing my existing databases. I searched google, and found a similar query here with a solution.

[Deleted MySQL "root" user (using phpMyAdmin)...how to restore?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124871/deleted-mysql-root-user-using-phpmyadmin-how-to-restore)

However, I tried most of the steps in the solution, but nothing came up. Could anyone please help me with a solution to add root user as well as databases back in phpMyAdmin using XAMPP localhost? I'm a novice, so need step-by-step instructions please. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Dupe [Deleted MySQL "root" user (using phpMyAdmin)...how to restore?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124871/deleted-mysql-root-user-using-phpmyadmin-how-to-restore)

Comment: If you think your question is not a duplicate please explain what steps you performed and how exactly they did not help.

Comment: I followed steps 1-3 of the solution in the post linked, but could not access MySQL console. I also tried resetroot but nothing changed.